# Convert text to Number in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
iif ([fieldname]<>”000000”, clng([fieldname])
```

this is ok and returns “000000” into `null` and converts my fieldname into numbers

But the function

```
iif ([fieldname]<>”000000” or “000006", clng([fieldname])
```

does not return 000006 into null but instead into a number. I need both "000000" and “000006"  to be `null`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 iif (([fieldname]<>”000000” And [fieldname] <> “000006"), clng([fieldname]))
```

Your condition doesn't do the check you require. Instead it tries a binary OR between `[fieldname]<>”000000”` and `000006` which is always true, hence it applies `Clng` to all values.

Comment: Thanks - I tried and gives me error saying function contain wrong number of arguments

Comment: *"I need both "000000" and “000006" to be null"* - you need AND instead of OR in your IIf condition.

Comment: Thanks @Andre. Good spot